# Connect to Frida server on same device

Tags: applications

Is there a way to use Frida on a rooted emulator without the need for ADB? For example, install Frida tools on the emulator with Termux and copy the frida-server binary on the device, connect to it, and use Frida locally without the need for a separate device.

Comment: I only know the way to modify the apk file and to embed Frida gadget + a frida script inside the APK so that the APK will automatically execute the gadget and the script when started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `frida-gadget.so`. `frida-gadget.so` is a Frida's shared library meant to be loaded by programs to be instrumented (when the Injected mode of operation isn’t suitable). By simply loading the library it will allow you to interact with it using existing Frida-based tools like frida-trace. It also supports a fully autonomous approach where it can run scripts off the filesystem without any outside communication, and without root.
Look at https://github.com/ax/apk.sh, patching an APK is simple as running `./apk.sh patch <apk_name> --arch arm`.